# Need Help Setting Chrome as Default

Tags: powershell, batch-file

This may look a little strange, but I am trying to open powershell within a batch file to set Chrome as the default browser. I know this seems counter intuitive, but I promise for this application and the rest of the content in the batch file, this is the route I have to go.

This is the bit of string I am using

```
start  powershell.exe -noexit -command "$chromePath = "${Env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Google\Chrome\Application\" 
$chromeApp = "chrome.exe"
$chromeCommandArgs = "--make-default-browser" & "$chromePath$chromeApp" $chromeCommandArgs
```

but once it launches powershell, I get a missing terminator error.

Specifically this

```
The string is missing the terminator: ".
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString
```

Can anyone help a novice identify what I'm missing?

Comment: It tells you exactly what the error is, look at your first line, specifically the  "

Comment: You are running a command which has imbalanced doublequotes. You are also trying to run 3 different commands but only one of them is being run as a PowerShell command. To run all 3 lines they should be concatenated with a semicolon separator.

Comment: I guess that's the part I'm having time identifying. Which ", and do I need another one somewhere to close the command? I'm still fairly new to this. Appreciate the help!

Comment: If you want to put double quotes inside a double-quoted string you need to escape them.

Comment: Could anyone show me what this would look like if it were put together correctly?

Comment: @MrTomatoFace, why not try some stuff based on the advice thus far. That way, your question isn't a 'write my code for me' type thing, which would be off topic here.

Comment: Please also note that the third line will not work ""--make-default-browser" & "$chromePath$chromeApp" $chromeCommandArgs" you might want to look into creating PowerShell objects for this i.e. $chromeCommandArgs = @{ argument1 = "" [newline] argument2 = "" }